# Battery saver mode does not work

Tags: pokemon-go

My battery saver mode on Pokemon go does not work. When I turn my phone upside down, it does not dim the screen. How can I make it work?

Comment: The battery saver mode works for me when I turn the phone upside down. It will still have the app running, count walks and notify you when a pokemon shows up, but the screen will be dimmed with a faint PoGo logo.

Comment: @David "PoGo" - love it

Comment: What phone are you using?

Comment: It's not activating for me either. Not just you. Using a Samsung Galaxy Grand Prime

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with your phones gyroscope, look up your model and see if it even has one, my moto x play does not and therefore cannot use ar or battery saver

Answer (score 1):

Battery saver mode works by detecting if your phone is in an "idle position" and making the screen black. Make sure the setting is ON, then restart your game. Try placing your phone on a table and seeing if the screen turns black.

If it doesn't, it could be a hardware problem with your phone's internal gyroscopes

Comment: Don't place it on a table, it won't activate for a lot of people like that, just hold it down by your side. The battery saver mode is supposed to let you rest your arm while walking, or having the phone in your pocket, it's supposed to be activated if you turn your phone 180 degrees, not holding it flat upside down.

Answer (score 1):

On Android I wouldn't recommend using the battery save mode at all. Three of my friends and myself have had issues with the game disconnecting from the game servers and being unable to reconnect afterwards, should the game go to power saving mode. Phones are One+ 1, One+ 2 and a couple of Samsungs. The issue is consistent too: Every time PoGo activates the battery save mode the connection is lost until the game is restarted.

This is an issue with the version 0.29.0, it might be resolved in the very near future.

Comment: I'm using 0.29.2 on an Android - and not a particularly good one either - and I haven't had any issue with connection. So either that did fix it or the signal in your region may be weaker.